# Is it possible to modify the jquery objects and the retrieve the modified objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to modify an object resulting from $('#some_id'), and everything seems to work fine, but when I ask back for my modified object it has no changes at all.

```
$('#log_container').log
undefined
$('#log_container').log = {}
Object {}
$('#log_container').log
undefined
```

Why `$('#log_container').log` is `undefined` instead of what I explicitly assign in the previous line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because [`jQuery('some-selector')`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1) returns a new object every single time it is invoked:

```
function whatHappens(selector) {
  return {
    magic: 'here'
  }
}

whatHappens('when').log  // undefined
var result = whatHappens('when');
result.log = {};
var result2 = whatHappens('when');
result === result2  // false
result.log   // {}
result2.log  // undefined
```

If you need some data to always be available on the object you can:

- Use the [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method to set the data on the DOM node:

  ```
  $('#log_container').data('log', {});
  $('#log_container').data('log');
  ```
- Store a reference to the jQuery collection:

  ```
  var $logContainer = $('#log_container');
  $logContainer.log = {};
  $logContainer.log;  // {}
  ```
- Update the returned jQuery collection's `[[Prototype]]` (`jQuery.prototype`, commonly referred to by it's alias, `jQuery.fn`) to add the data / methods (this makes the data available to *all* jQuery collections, past, present and future):

  ```
  jQuery.fn.log = function yourLoggingMethod() {
    // Available on all jQuery collections now
    // Shared state - don't put things like {} or []
    // on here unless you intend to have a mutable "global".
  };
  ```

  Then you can just create collections as normal:

  ```
  var $logContainer = $('#log_container');
  $logContainer.log  // function yourLoggingMethod
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Every time you run `$('#log_container')` it creates a new jQuery object.

If you want to specifically modify a jquery object for some reason (which you probably should not; there are much better alternatives), assign it to a variable; then modify and use that variable;

```
var test = $('#log_container');
test.log = {};
console.log(test.log);
```

Comment: This is a half-answer: "There are much better alternatives". Please provide a couple examples and why you think they are better.